# Access VBA opening Temp.xls instead of set filepath

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have code in Access that opens an excel template then saves it based on filepath.  The template is then closed and I have put code in that will open the recently saved file.  However, the file that opens is the temp.xlsm.
I have spent hours trying to figure out where I am going wrong but no luck, unless I am asking google the wrong question.
This is the part of my code that opens the template, saves it as, and then closes the template to reopen the saved file.  Debugs are giving the correct file paths so I can't understand why the temp file keeps opening.

```
    Dim objXLApp As Object
    Dim objXLBook As Object
    Dim objXLBookNew As Object
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    FilePath = Forms!fm_MainMenu!fm_FilePath_Template.Form!File_Path & "\" & Forms!fm_MainMenu!fm_FilePath_Template.Form!File_Name & "." & Forms!fm_MainMenu!fm_FilePath_Template.Form!File_Type
  
Debug.Print FilePath
    
    Set objXLBook = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    objXLApp.Application.Visible = True
    
    Maxletter = DMax("LetterID", "tbl_ReportNo", "[JobNo]= '" & [Forms]![fm_JobHeader]![Job_No] & "'")
    Me.ReportNo = DLookup("Letter", "tbl_LetterID", "Letter_ID = " & Maxletter)

    objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("AI13") = [Forms]![fm_JobHeader]![Job_No] & DLookup("Letter", "tbl_LetterID", "Letter_ID = " & Maxletter)
    objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("N15") = [Forms]![fm_JobHeader]![Client].Column(1)
    objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("AF14") = [Forms]![fm_JobHeader]![PONo]
    objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("S17") = [Forms]![fm_JobHeader]![JobDescription]
    objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("AT15") = Now()
    objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("T13") = Me.Discipline.Column(1)
    objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("Z13") = Me.Type.Column(1)
    objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("AT16") = Me.RequestWONo
    objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("S19") = Me.SiteLocation.Column(1)


Dim path_ As String
    path_ = Forms!fm_MainMenu!fm_FilePath_Report.Form!File_Path & "\" & [Forms]![fm_JobHeader]![Job_No] & DLookup("Letter", "tbl_LetterID", "Letter_ID = " & Maxletter)

Dim name_ As String
    name_ = [Forms]![fm_JobHeader]![Job_No] & DLookup("Letter", "tbl_LetterID", "Letter_ID = " & Maxletter) & ".xlsm"

Debug.Print path_
Debug.Print name_

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not .FolderExists(path_) Then .CreateFolder path_
End With

objXLBook.SaveCopyAs FileName:=path_ & "\" & name_
objXLBook.Close False
Set objXLBook = Nothing

Dim path2_ As String
    path2_ = Forms!fm_MainMenu!fm_FilePath_Report.Form!File_Path & "\" & [Forms]![fm_JobHeader]![Job_No] & DLookup("Letter", "tbl_LetterID", "Letter_ID = " & Maxletter)

Dim name2_ As String
    name2_ = [Forms]![fm_JobHeader]![Job_No] & DLookup("Letter", "tbl_LetterID", "Letter_ID = " & Maxletter) & ".xlsm"
   Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objXLBookNew = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open(path2_ & "\" & name2_)
Debug.Print path2_
Debug.Print name2_
    objXLApp.Application.Visible = True
    
DoCmd.Hourglass False ' turn off hourglass

Set objXLBookNew = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Set rec = Nothing
```

---

```
Debug of file_ C:\Users\OneDrive\Current Working Docs\Reports Database\ABC123AY
Debug of path_ ABC123AY.xlsm
Debug of file2_ C:\Users\OneDrive\Current Working Docs\Reports Database\ABC123AY
Debug of path2_ ABC123AY.xlsm
```

But file that is being opened is

```
C:\Temp\Temp.xlsm
```

Maybe I have been looking at this too long and the obvious is staring me in the face but I am gaining frustration.  Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: you're using SaveCopyAs any reasons why not to use SaveAs ? Is it a network path?

Comment: you are creating  2 objects with the same name Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") without close or set it to nothing , bed practice. there is no need for that . delete the second statement  and continue using the same objXLApp object to open the new workbook. and like the previous user wrote use SaveAs

Comment: Simple but effective fix, thank you @pascalb I change it to SaveAs and then no longer needed to close and reopen the file.

Comment: I also removed the second object statement, thank you @xShen for the advise.